# OData.Net doesn't allow contains in the $filter

Tags: asp.net, odata, visual-studio-2015

I read everywhere that in OData v3 you should use `substringof()` and in v4 you should use `contains()`. I installed Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData from NuGet that says version **5.5.1**.

Strangely, contains() doesn't work. I am getting the following error:

> {"message":"The query specified in the URI is not valid. An unknown function with name 'contains' was found. This may also be a key lookup on a navigation property, which is not allowed." ... }

Conversely, `substringof()` works fine. Is it supposed to be that way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The NuGet package version is 5.5.1, but that does not refer to the supported OData version. As OData v1-3 and OData v4 have some non-compatible changes, there are two versions of the WebAPI OData package:

**ASP.NET Web API 2.2 for OData v1-3**

*Package Id: Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData, Version: 5.5.1*

**ASP.NET Web API 2.2 for OData v4**

*Package Id: Microsoft.AspNet.OData, Version: 5.6.0*

So you are using OData v3 at the moment and the error message is correct, contains() is not defined in OData v3

Comment: what you are saying is absolutely correct *in VS2013*. However, in VS2015 there is only **1** package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData (notice absence of "for OData vx") and therefore my question. Does that mean that Microsoft.AspNet.OData is not yet available?

Comment: The available packages should not depend on the IDE, but on the ASP or .NET version you're using. On the project page I do not see any hint that the two OData packages were combined (https://github.com/OData/WebApi), and for the new ASP.NET 5/MVC6, there seems to be no OData support at all yet (https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/229).

Please try to create an instance of the ODataFeed object, then check the namespace that is imported. Microsoft.OData.Core is v4 and Microsoft.Data.OData is v3.

Comment: Thanks. It imports Microsoft.Data.OData which is consistent with v3 behavior (substringof works and contains doesn't)

Answer (score 0):

The two NuGet packages which enables OData for WebApi are the following:

**Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData** for OData v1-3

**Microsoft.AspNet.OData** for OData v4

Even though v4 does not say WebApi in the name, its still the one to use. The naming has changed and reflects the Package Id (lukehellrunner included these)

Current versions are 5.7.0 for both.

Comment: Am I correct in seeing that the only difference between your post and lukehellrunner's answers is that the versions have changed? If that's the case, I think a better approach here would be to edit lukehellrunner's answer to update the versions, rather than posting a whole new answer.

Comment: What i tried to point out was that the packages lukehellrunner mentioned was wrong and do not exsist i the NuGet library. You might be right that i could have edited lukehellrunners answer instead to correct the error.