# I get an error when use Odata query with contains

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

Here is controller code

```
[EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<Product> Get()
    {
        var productRepository = new ProductRepository();
        return productRepository.Retrieve().AsQueryable();
    }
```

Here is Retrieve() method

```
internal List<Product> Retrieve()
    {
        var filePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/product.json");

        var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);

        var products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(json);

        return products;
    }
```

And Product class

```
   public class Product
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

}
```

Other filters like $filter=Price+gt+6 or $top=4 and $skip=1 work fine. WebApi.OData package version=5.7.0

Error: 
"The query specified in the URI is not valid. An unknown function with name 'contains' was found.

Comment: please share your error with us!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OData.Net doesn't allow contains in the $filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31085595/odata-net-doesnt-allow-contains-in-the-filter)

Answer (score 3):

`substringof()` is a **V3** function while `contains()` is a **V4** function.

Try `contains`:

```
$filter=contains(Name,'value')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using an OData library package for OData version 3, but `contains` is a version 4 function. You can either query with the `substringof` function defined in version 3, or switch to a [package that supports OData version 4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.OData/).